# In Windows, can I install a python library on Linux subsystem, and run it from Windows?

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I work on Windows, and have Windows Subsystem for Linux that I use for installing Python with some Python libraries.
I can run these Python libraries from within the Linux subsystem.
But, I also want to run them from within Windows (e.g., from an IDE that I install on Windows).

Can Windows run a Python library that is installed on a Linux subsysten? Or do I have to install all the Python libraries twice (on Linux and on Windows)?

Comment: No; Windows cannot use Linux Python libraries.

Comment: Provide an example. I'll try that.